# Retrieve all window opened on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, powershell

I try to retrieve some information(x,y,width,height and title) for all opened window on Windows with a simple C++ code(see below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int     iCmdShow)
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
    //system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
char class_name[255];
char title[255];
int tmpWidth;
int tmpHeight;
HWND currenthwnd;
RECT WindowRect;

GetClassName(hwnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
GetWindowText(hwnd,title,sizeof(title));
GetWindowRect(hwnd,&WindowRect);

//if(WindowRect.left>-50 && title != "" && title != NULL && strlen(title)>0){
    tmpHeight = WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top;
    tmpWidth = WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left;
    cout <<"@@##@@"<<title<<",(@@#@@)";
    cout <<WindowRect.left<<",(@@#@@)";
    cout <<WindowRect.top<<",(@@#@@)";
    cout <<tmpWidth<<",(@@#@@)";
    cout <<tmpHeight<<",(@@#@@)";
    currenthwnd=GetForegroundWindow();
    if (currenthwnd!=hwnd){
       cout <<title<<",(@@#@@)false";
    }else{
       cout <<title<<",(@@#@@)true";
    }
 //}

 return TRUE;
}
```

But I encountered some issue with this code, I also try with PowerShell with Get-Process function, but this function doesn't return all opened windows but all existing process.

How can I retrieve title, x,y, with, heigth of all opened window ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: what issue did you encounter?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with 'I encountered some issue with this code'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powershell you can use the [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com) Module and wrote something like this:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}  | 
% {$_.processname + "-" + $_.mainwindowtitle;
       Get-WindowPosition -Window $_.handle }
```

This is a result example for my actual powershell windows:

```
powershell - Posh - Admin
Location : {X=4,Y=44}
Size     : {Width=885, Height=129}
X        : 4
Y        : 44
Width    : 885
Height   : 129
Left     : 4
Top      : 44
Right    : 889
Bottom   : 173
IsEmpty  : False
```